# Which of client-side server side web-programming is better?

Tags: client-side, server-side

Which of client-side or server-side web-programming produces the best results for websites?

Is the following a correct analysis of some major web-programming platforms?

```
ASP - server side
JSP - server side
Coldfusion - server side
Javascript - client side
PHP - server side
```

What sort of websites are better done using client-side, and what websites are better done using server-side?

Comment: This is mostly incoherent. Can you clarify what you're asking? Note that your table is correct, as far as it goes.

Comment: This is sort of like asking, "Which is better in a car; to have an engine or a transmission?"

Answer (score 3):

There is no answer to the "which is better" question, because server side programming and client side programming are very different.

Your questions so far indicate [analysis paralysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) where you're fixating on the tools to solve your problem rather than the problem itself. Pick something (it doesn't matter what, we're here to help) and learn it!